# Jquery Mobile - Navbar not fixed after scroll in an iframe

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, iframe, scroll

I have successfully implemented a fixed navbar on all the pages of my application except on one of the page.
This page contains an iframe that has a 100% height and 100% width.

When I load the page, everything is normal.

[image: What is should be always like]

If I scroll everything is still normal.

But next, I click on link inside the iframe

And then I scroll, the navbar and headerbar are not fixed anymore during the scroll. And then they go back to their position.
[image]

Here is some code to help you out

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>My Page</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jqm-icon-pack-2.1.2-fa.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div data-role="page" id="boutique">
    <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed" data--tap-toggle="true">
        <h1>Boutique</h1>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content" style="padding:0px">
        <iframe  style="width:100%; height:100%; border:0px; margin:0px" src="http://autotech.gazoline.net/index.php?mobile_theme_ok" rel="external">
        </iframe>
    </div>
    <div data-role="footer" data-id="myfooter" data-transition="pop" data-position="fixed" data-tap-toggle="true">
    <div data-role="navbar" data-grid="b">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#articles" data-icon="file">Articles</a></li>
        <li><a href="#videos" data-icon="play">Vid&eacute;os</a></li>
        <li><a class="ui-btn-active ui-state-persist" href="#boutique" data-icon="shopping-cart">Boutique2</a></li>
    </ul>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this attribute in header make this

```
data--tap-toggle="true"
```

you should write it as the footer

```
data-tap-toggle="true"
```

Also you don't need to write this code because the default case is "true"
If you want to disable toggling when click , you should make it "false"

Best Regards

Comment: Hello, thanks for the answer. This code is there because I tried setting it to false previously.

Comment: What happened after setting it to false with a correct format , did this solve your issue.

Comment: Nope I did not solve my problem. I tried to implement this: [link](http://outof.me/native-scrolling-in-jquery-mobilephonegap-applications/) It almost worked but still not. So for now, I'm just hiding this page :(